# Is there any way to open Cocoa app as an sheet on Browser?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Is there any way to open Cocoa app as an sheet on Browser (Safari for example) ? 
 More details - you go to some url, and modal window appeared on browser it should be Cocoa app (like window with some UI and buttons).

I have extension, plugin already ready to handle open url,etc.. I wonder is there any way to do that, in Windows OS  it was possible through getting Browser Window Handle from plugin but OSX won't let do that. Any ideas appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: why? can't you just open the app?

Comment: @xlc You mean manually? What I need, is when you open some specific URL,( my extension/plugin have logic for handling it) display Cocoa app  modal on browser- (like alert is displayed on browser, but it should be Cocoa app). I know this can be done by Javascript injection to create UI, but for security reason I need Cocoa app. I hope it make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be done on iOS or OS X as a modal. The only thing you can do is 
Register a custom URL scheme, and Safari will switch to your app
 When the user taps on a link. Alternatively, you could build a JavaScript bookmarklet, but I'm assuming you don't want to do that.

Comment: Sorry, did you mean OSX? Yes I don't want to use Javascript for security reasons..

Comment: I'm assuming you looked at the Safari JavaScript API; it enables a few things not available on a simple JavaScript website: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/

Comment: Yes I have looked at that, there is SafariBrowserWindow API, but didn't find any way to get  (NSWindow *) from it,so Cocoa app can be opened as a sheet on it.

Comment: How about using a simple JavaScript modal to launch an external app with a custom URL scheme?

Comment: Will be that app in JavaScript modal window? I mean will be it modal? It must give user feeling like it's part of browser, just modal window. Like alerts, or javascript modals does.